# JPA BigInteger is beeing mapped to decimal for MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

I have a simple class with an id property that I would like to be created as a bigint.

Here is the property

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@NotNull
public java.math.BigInteger id;
```

However this is generates this:

```
id decimal(19,2) not null auto_increment
```

I can of course add

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "bigint(20)")
```

And then it works but I can't undarstand why dose JPA prefer to match to decimal instead of bigint.

The generated mapping also causes an error for an invalid id because the decimal is not auto_incrementable.

I'm using spring boot with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependancy.
The configurations is as follows:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Any ideas?

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT applies only to integer and floating-point types. see MySQL manual, CREATE TABLE. AUTO_INCREMENT don't apply to DECIMAL

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. The question is more about why does jpa map the BigInteger type of decimal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JDBC type BIGINT represents a 64-bit signed integer value between -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807.
The corresponding SQL type BIGINT is a non-standard extension to SQL. In practice the SQL BIGINT type is not yet currently implemented by any of the major databases, and we recommend that its use should be avoided in portable code.

The recommended Java mapping for the BIGINT type is as a Java **long**.

Comment: "In practice the SQL BIGINT type is not yet currently implemented by any of the major databases, and we recommend that its use should be avoided in portable code." Really? Which major database doesn't support `BIGINT`?

Comment: Quite probably because BIGINTs can be unsigned (in MySQL at least, if not in other RDBMSs).

The only Java type that can hold the full range of a 64-bit unsigned integer is BigInteger. It would be incorrect to use a long for this, as this would convert 18446744073709551615 (264 - 1) to -1.

Comment: Okay. I tried changing the BigInteger to a Long and that was translated to a bigint(20) in MySQL. So to sum up, the BigInteger was in a way to big so it was mapped to a decimal since that is the datatype that could support the java type. At least that is my understanding of it.